# How to create datetime object from a unicode string?

Tags: python, datetime, unicode, python-unicode

I am haviing trouble converting in python from this format:

```
u'08:00:00'
```

to a `datetime` object like:

```
datetime.datetime(2017,02,22,8,0,0)
```

What is an easy way to do this?

I can do it by just parsing the string but looking for more elegant solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: this is unicode though not string.  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to parse the time string. You can do that by hand, or use `datetime.strptime()`:

```
from datetime import datetime

s = u'08:00:00'
t = datetime.strptime(s, '%H:%M:%S').time()
```

`strptime()` doesn't care that you give it a unicode string. That will give you a `datetime.time` object:

```
>>> t
datetime.time(8, 0)
```

Then use [`datetime.combine()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) to combine the time with today's date:

```
from datetime import date

dt = datetime.combine(date.today(), t)
```

This will give you the required `datetime.datetime` object:

```
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 24, 8, 0)
```